# Problem in UITableView and UIScrollView

Tags: iphone

My table has more than 10 rows with 50 row height....so i can't select my last row....so i have set UIScrollView and add this table into UIScrollView.

Table display perfectly but which rows are displayed in UIScrollView, these are not selectable.

How can i get this row selecablt in UIScrollView. If anyone body know then pls tell me wha to do?

Thanks,
Haresh.

Answer (score 3):

Putting a UITableView inside a UIScrollView won't work, beause UITableView *is* a UIScrollView.  You're going to have to work out why UITableView won't scroll properly for you on its own.

Check how you initialize it and look at some of Apple's example UITableView code to see what is different.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your navigation bar, toolbar or some other control is hiding that last row.  Check to make sure the tableview partly under another control.